# How to distribute data evenly among executers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I read a dataframe from parquet files using `read.parquet()` from dfs and cached it. But, how do I evenly distribute among executors.

[image]

I use Cloudera cluster, adding just if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the data from Parquet RDD and use broadcast variable to make it accessable in executors.

```
RDD.collect()
```

[`Broadcast Variables`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables)